# How to write a loop to load, modify and save a video file in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, video, save, load

I need to load a video file (.AVI) in R, to extract a frame from it and to save this frame as a image (.jpg), named like the video from which it was extracted.
Throught the package magick I manage to do it, but now I need to automatize this process, and I have a problem. The first part of the loop seems to work, but the second part does not. I have also tried to create a single for loop but without success.
Who can help me?
Thanks!

```
# For a single video (ok):
library(magick)
video <- image_read_video("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\IMG_0020.AVI", fps=0.1)
image_write(video, path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\IMG_0020.jpg", format = "jpg")

# For a entire folder (it doesn't work):
setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_name")
v <- list.files("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_name\\", full.names = F, pattern="*.AVI")
for(i in 1:length(v)) {
  p <- assign(v[i],
  image_read_video(fps=0.1, paste("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_name\\",  
                           v[i], sep='')))
}

for(i in 1:length(p)) {
  assign(p[i], 
  image_write(format = "jpg", paste("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_name",
                         p[i], sep='')))
}
```

Comment: You overwrite `p` in each iteration of your first look but then reference `p[i]` in your second.  Is this intentional?  Also, you are almost certainly a victim of *lazy evaluation*.  I suggest changing your `for` loops to `lapply`, which forces evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for`-loop-`assign`-logic is broken. Actually using `assing` doesn't make any sense in this context, at least for me.

Combine your loops into one single loop like this:

```r
library(magick)

# For a entire folder (it doesn't work):
setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder_name")

videos_list <- list.files(full.names = F, pattern = "*.AVI")

for(file in videos_list) {
  p <- image_read_video(fps = 0.1, file)
  
  image_name <- gsub("\\.AVI", "\\.JPG", file)
  
  image_write(p, path = image_name, format = "jpg")
}
```

This should create one `jpg`-image for each `avi`-video in your working directory.

Since you already defined your working directory, you don't need the paths.

As Limey stated, you could use `lapply` instead of a `for`-loop:

```r
lapply(video_list, 
       function(file) {
         image_write(image_read_video(fps = 0.1, file), 
                     path = gsub("\\.AVI", "\\.JPG", file), 
                     format = "jpg")
         }
       )
```

should return the same result.